# Invalid default value for 'updated_at' in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, database, timestamp

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid default value for
>   'updated_at' Query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS saved_query (id int(11)
NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,name varchar(255) NOT NULL,description
 varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,query longtext,params_json
longtext,created_at timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,updated_at
=timestamp NOT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (id)) Parameters: []
```

Pasting the query for readability:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS saved_query 
( 
 id          INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
 name        VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
 description VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
 query       LONGTEXT, 
 params_json LONGTEXT, 
 created_at  TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
 updated_at  TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY (id) 
)
```

Mysql version is `5.7.13`. The query above works in versions `5.6` and `5.5`. The following query works in `5.7` but not in `<5.7` versions:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS saved_query 
  ( 
     id          INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
     name        VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
     description VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
     query       LONGTEXT, 
     params_json LONGTEXT, 
     created_at  TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
     updated_at  TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
     PRIMARY KEY (id) 
  )
```

The error in `5.6` is:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect table definition; there
>   can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or
>   ON UPDATE clause Query:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS saved_query (id
 int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,name varchar(255) NOT NULL,description
 varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,query longtext,params_json
 longtext,created_at timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,updated_at
 timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  PRIMARY KEY (id)) Parameters: []
```

What should be the query that works in all these versions?

Comment: what has this got to do with java?

Comment: Change created_at to just TIMESTAMP and fill it in the first record INSERT. Logical in hindsight isn't it?

Answer (score 8):

The problem is because of sql_modes. You have to remove the sql_mode to make it work. Remove these SQL modes

```
NO_ZERO_IN_DATE
NO_ZERO_DATE
```

or

before you run any query, paste this code in the first line of your code:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
```

or

before you run any query, paste this code in the first line:

```
SET sql_mode = '';
```

Answer (score -1):

`TIMESTAMP` can not be `NULL`, and mysql add `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for column. But may be only one column width `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Just use `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS saved_query 
  ( 
     id          INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
     name        VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
     description VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
     query       LONGTEXT, 
     params_json LONGTEXT,
     created_at  TIMESTAMP DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
     updated_at  TIMESTAMP DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
     PRIMARY KEY (id) 
  )
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Error: `Error: Invalid default value for 'created_at'
SQLState:  42000
ErrorCode: 1067`